# Can anyone show me how to make links markup in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

I'd like to make link markups something like this

User List / User A / Blog

It could be something like this also User List / User A / Profile

User List could be Model.
User A would be given by parameter
Blog or Profile would be an action(Method)

How can I pass these information to view from my controller if view was something like this.
you can obviously modify!! Thanks

```
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
          <li>

          <% if !@FirstDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @FirstDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@SecondDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @SecondDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@ThirdDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @ThirdDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@FourthDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @FourthDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>        

          </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use link_to helper in your views. For example:

```
<%= link_to "My link", "link_url" %>
```

For your AR records you can use this syntax:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user %>
<%= link_to article.title, article %>
# ... etc.
```

**UPD**

I don't understand what you want to do. In views you can use instance variables that defined in actions. For example:

```
@links = [
  { label: "My link",      destination: some_path },
  { label: "Another link", destination: "path/path" },
  { label: "Third link",   destination: third_list_path }
]
```

Than in views you can:

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <%= link_to link[:label], link[:destination] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I know how to use link_to. What I wanna know is how to make it variable. The code I wrote in my question is written in  application.html.erb.  So it'll be changed every time depending on what controller, action methods, and parameters. So those information should be past from controller. How can I make my view flexible to adjust to this situation??

Comment: You can get controller and action through params[:controller] and params[:action]. Then dependent from controller and action you can use special partial in your layout:

    <%= render partial: "#{params[:action]}_my_partial_name" %>

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if I wanna put label, and destination link path for that variable link tag? how can I pass them to view from controller?